# how to add label into line type in charts.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying using line chart from plugin Chart.js on my site, and I'm trying to find the way of display data at point value.

can somebody help me...

Mi current javascript code is:

```
var lineChartData = {
    labels : ["00:00","06:00","12:00", "18:00"],
    datasets : [
                label: "PR",
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#FF0040",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : ['1','10','5','15']


        ]
}
```

This is what i want at my line chart:

[image: Expected result]

Comment: is it you want the tooltip or you want it drawn on the point when the graph is rendered?

Comment: i want it drawn on the point